# grouping items in regex of ELB logs

Tags: javascript, regex

In this regex, https://regex101.com/r/SzzJDE/7 how to I group the `__utm.gif`

I have

```
\"(\S+)\s+\w+:\/\/([\w\-\.]*):\S+(\/\S+\s+)([^\"]+)\"
```

But I unsure how best to extract it?

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the way?

Comment: please extract your link content and add a [mcve] directly to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your regex101 sample, you'll see that it's the third group that currently captures your `__utm.gif` ; it starts with `\/`, which you don't want to group, then matches up to the end of the url with `\S+\s+`. Precede that part with something that will only match up to the `?` excluded, and group that  :

```
\"(\S+)\s+\w+:\/\/([\w\-\.]*):\S+(\/([^?]+)\S+\s+)([^\"]+)\"
                                    ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression

```
(?:\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b:[0-9]+\s+)+(.*)\s+"GET\s+(http(?:.*)\.(?:gif))
```

Demo
https://regex101.com/r/WKbwhk/1